# Log formula proof and explanation

Tags: proof-explanation, logarithms

How can we prove this identity?

$$a^{\log_b n}=n^{\log_b a}$$

Thanks.

Comment: OK, I see your edit. I approved the edit for you but it needs one more approval. So if someone will be so kind . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking $\log_a$ of both sides, we get

\begin{align*}
&\log_a(a^{\log_b n}) = \log_a(n^{\log_b a})\\
\implies & \log_b n=\log_b a\log_a n\\
\implies & \frac{\log_b n}{\log_b a} = \log_a n,
\end{align*}

so the problem is equivalent to the [change of base formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Change_of_base_formula).

Comment: On your first line you have $n^{\log_ba}$ whereas OP has $b^{\log_an}$

Comment: The current post had previously been edited incorrectly. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much Philip!

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $\log_m w$ where $m>0; m\ne 1; w> 0$ is that there is a unique real $k$ where $m^k = w$ and $\log_m w =k$ is defined to be that value.

Therefore for any $w\ge 0$ and $m\ne 1; m> 0$ we will *always* have $w = m^{\log_m w}$ because $\log_m w$ is defined to be the unique $k$ so that $m^k = w$ and so $m^{\log_m w} = m^k = w$.  Always.

So $a^{\log_b n} = (b^{\log_b a})^{\log_b n} = b^{\log_b a \times \log_b n}$

But $n^{\log_b a} = (b^{\log_b n})^{\log_b a} = b^{\log_b n\times \log_b a}$.

And so both $a^{\log_b n}$ and $n^{\log_b a}$ are both equal to the same thing.